# How to read nth character in a textview/string

Tags: java, android, string, textview

I have a textview with @id `checkMe`. The text saved in this text view is "`00100`".

I've parsed the text from the `change me` textview to a string called `getText`.

I have an onclick method using a button called `btnChange`. I'd like the application to check the 3rd character in the string and if it is 1, `//Do something` (I have the 'do something  figured out).

I have tried goolging an answer for this but have only found results looking for the nth occurance of a character or 'replace nth character' solutions.

EDIT: it seems `regionMatches` is the function I'm after but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The String class in Java has a `charAt` method to get a particular character. It is 0-indexed, so you want index `2`. Of course, dcharms mentioned, you should check first that you have a sufficiently long string.

```
if (getText.length() > 2 && getText.charAt(2) == '1') // do something.
```

Here is the Android version of the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29).

Comment: Make sure you add a `getText.length() > 2` to that as well to avoid an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! edit: will accept answer when it lets me. Not used to such a speedy response

Answer (score 1):

The first answer is simpler but this would also work, in case you need to manipulate other digits.  This will convert the strings to a char array.  Then the char can be converted into int and placed in either an arraylist or an array.

```
String a= "12345";
    char [] blah=a.toCharArray();     
    int [] numbers = new int[blah.length];
    ArrayList<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < blah.length; i++) {
        numbers [i] =Character.getNumericValue(blah[i]);
        list.add(Character.getNumericValue(blah[i]));
    }
```